# How to optimize imports automatically after each save in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I want to learn how can I **automatically optimize imports after each save** as we do Eclipse(*save actions*).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA offers an option to **Optimize imports on the fly** in `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Auto Import` and **Optimize imports** option in the `Commit Project` dialog.

Comment: Enabling this option by default will produce a lot of diffs in imports after commit if team members are using different IDEs, it's the main reason to make it disabled by default.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: that can be fixed by requiring all imports to be used and having a fixed order of imports (both of which IDEs can easily do, so it should not add work for anyone). Then the only diffs in imports are when imports actually change.

Comment: @JoachimSauer how can you define this order of imports, etc. in IntelliJ please ?

Comment: @miss_R For Java, it's under `Settings` | `Editor` | `Code Style` | `Java` | `Imports` tab | `Import Layout` section in IntelliJ 2016.3.4. I presume other languages have it in their respective settings. :)

Comment: If you're going to do this, you also probably want to add something like Checkstyle to your build, and use it to enforce the fixed order of imports for your project.

Answer (score 69):

The mentioned answer works, but there is also the Intellij "save actions" plugin available from the JetBrains plugin repository that does that (as well as other things): **[Intellij Save Actions Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642?pr=idea_ce)**.

**Installation**

File > Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories... > Search 'Save Actions' > Category 'Code tools'

**Disclaimer**

I'm the plugin developer

Comment: is this really necessary? i'm so confused what the Import Option "optimize on the fly" does if it does not optimize when the file is saved/edited... it seems strange and a bug that this "Save Action" is even required.  :)  that said, what a live-saver!!

Comment: I think the import option "optimize on the fly" will optimise when you import new types, and when you paste code, but it won't touch existing imports if you don't explicitly ask for it. There are no "save actions" that you can configure in Intellij.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found this to be a much less aggressive option than IntelliJ's built-in "Optimize imports on the fly". With the built-in option often imports got swapped around just by opening a file; thanks to your plugin this won't and can't happen. The option to reformat on save is also much appreciated! :) :)

Comment: This is the actual answer for optimize the imports upon save, not just after a commit.

Comment: @AlexandreDuBreuil I'm trying to find out a way for the optimize imports not scrolling to the top of the file. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @Delfic a similar issue was opened on github can you describe it there? https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/92

Comment: This plugin seems to be the ONLY way to get IntelliJ to automatically delete unused imports. It also has a bunch of other great features.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 17):

*First step:*

```
CTRL + SHIFT + A or CMD + SHIFT + A (for mac)
```

*Second step:*

Search Optimize imports

*Third step:*

Switch ON the option

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In version 'Ultimate 2016.2' it is:

File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the fly