# Prevent Intellij IDEA to change assert imports

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

First of all, when I create a test class via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, IDEA automatically puts

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

into the class. In the same time a popup dialog apperas an asks me whether to add this new file to git. By hitting yes the file is added but the import disappears. I can understand that because the unit methods are empty, just declared bodys. After implementing the test with an assert I have to manually add the static import again. That is the first behavior. The second is that after I close the file and reopen it after some time again IDEA replaces the wildcard assert import with only the asserts I used in my unit test, e. g. only

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
```

How can I prevent this quite annoying behavior? I already tried to use a code template where I copied the template of "Class" and added the static import but this did not help me.

Comment: You most likely have checked the automatically the optimise imports (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704327/intellij-idea-how-to-optimize-imports-automatically-after-each-save)

Comment: I ll try it with unchecked option