# intellij idea cannot remove unused imports on save

Tags: intellij-idea

when I compile my project using `mvn`, it has below error

```
[ERROR] ... error: package com.sun.tools.attach does not exist
[ERROR] ...:[27,0] error: static import only from classes and interfaces
```

because in my code there are some unused imports

```
import static com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.list;
import static org.osgi.util.measurement.Unit.s;
```

but I have set `Optimize imports on the fly`, should it automatically remove these unused imports? Why still should I execute `ctrl+option+o` manually every file?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704327/how-to-optimize-imports-automatically-after-each-save-in-intellij).  There may not be an out-of-the-box way to do this in IntelliJ, but there is a plugin which can do this.

Comment: Are you using source control? As per Tim's answer, it's easy to configure intellij to optimize imports when you commit.

Comment: @vikingsteve yeah I use svn, and unfortunately I'm used to use svn command directly in terminal. So I have to install a plugin to implement this function.