# Am I the only one IDEA's Auto Import doesn't work for in Kotlin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

As you can read in the title "Optimize imports on the fly" does not work for me in **Kotlin**, but it works in **Java**, i. e. IDEA removes unused imports in my Java files but not in my Kotlin files.

Since I didn't find any posts related to this on the internet I was wondering if this bug is only occurring for me.

Maybe there is a good reason for this, if so feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error does no occur anymore. I am not sure which version of IDEA/Kotlin plugin it was fixed with, but I guess since August this year this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Works partly for me. That means when editing or saving a file unused imports are **not** cleaned. However, when I paste code, imports are automatically inserted.
I personally always use "Optimize imports".

Comment: So you mean the manual optimization? And I didn't know there is file saving in IntelliJ, is that an optional thing?

Comment: Yes, I mean manual optimization. It seems someone has written a plugin to support actions on saving actions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27706292/8082357)) (I haven't worked with that plugin so far).