# Is it possible for intellij to organize imports the same way as in Eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a project where all the team members are using Eclipse and I'm the only IDEA user. This creates a lot of noise from imports rearrangements. The order in which eclipse imports is: Java, Javax, Org, Com, everything else in alphabetical order. Is it possible to configure IDEA to follow these rules?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Some more details:  I ended up performing these steps to match out of the box eclipse organizing:

(in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `Java` > `imports`, as mentioned by @yole)

- set "class count to use import with '*'" to 99 (seems like you cannot turn this off)
- set this ordering for `Import Layout` (like eclipse defaults):

  ```
    static all other, 
    blank, 
    java.*, 
    blank, 
    javax.*, 
    blank, 
    org.*, 
    blank, 
    com.*, 
    blank, 
    all other imports
  ```

FWIW, there is an Intellij plugin called "[eclipse code formatter](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-code-formatter-intellij-plugin/wiki/HowTo)" that I evaluated for this purpose and ended up discarding, because it set up a separate shortcut (in OSX) that was already in use by core IDE functionality.

Comment: [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=6546) works totally fine, not sure what that shortcut problem was...

Comment: As an update, for IntelliJ 14.1 on a Mac, you can find these settings under Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style --> Java --> Imports (tab)

Comment: Note that you can edit the way the Eclipse Code Formatter order imports and that it overrides anything you change in IntelliJ's settings. Note too that it does not place any imports before java.*

Comment: Eclipse Code Formatter overrides stuff, so that it is like in Eclipse, if anything is not right, then it is a bug.

Comment: You can switch the eclipse code formatter as default one with the "Switch code formatter" action.
Saying so I still don't know the best solution

Comment: Note to disable start imports you just remove the java.util and other packages from the table below

Comment: I set up eclipse code  formatter including formatting and import order. Sometimes I ended up importing with * although the intellij formatting scheme and the eclipse scheme should not do that (class count 99 ). Currently I imported the eclipse formatter and manually added the imports as above.

Answer (score 49):

Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports | Import Layout

Comment: Settings | _Editor_ | Code Style | Java | Imports | Import Layout

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In update to Max's answer, the correct order for resolving the `checkstyle` warnings. I updated the following in IntelliJ:

```
static all other, 
blank 
com.*
java.* 
javax.*
org.*  
all other imports
```