# Custom formatting of the code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, formatting, format

Is there a way to create a custom formatting order of the code in IntelliJ? More specifically I am trying to change the default formatting and format my imports by type when pressing option+command+L together.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194980/104891 answer your question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder amazing thank you, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2019.3, `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java` is the place where you can control the coding style of your Java code.

You can create a duplicate the default one and edit the settings without touching the default one, or import another format like Google's.

Comment: Thanks. In addition to that I would follow the following format given from this query: stackoverflow.com/a/17194980/104891