# Get Import Suggestions in IntelliJ

Tags: import, intellij-idea, autocomplete

Is there a way to get a list of import suggestions in IntelliJ IDE? I'm looking for the equivalent of CTRL+SHIFT+O functionality from Eclipse, which automaticaly lists import suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my current machine (on Windows), it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, and the command is named "*Optimize imports*".

In general, in IntelliJ IDEA, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and press part of a command to find it and know the appropriate shortcut. Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (or if you're on 
a Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) and then search for "import" allows finding this command easily.

That said, it seems this command doesn't suggest imports like Eclipse does.

Comment: Thanks, @JB Nizet! Just to add to the answer - after typing Ctrl-Alt-O I was promped to the different declarations that I was missing imports and for each of them I needed to type Alt+Enter in order to actually import them. Thanks again : )

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way when there are multiple imports but you could take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608710/intellij-organize-imports for 'auto import' feature.