# IntelliJ Organize imports - also ambiguous

Tags: intellij-idea, import, keyboard-shortcuts

Note: The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608710/intellij-organize-imports) question is not satisfactory.

When I paste code containing `Level`, `List`, `Map`, etc, and press Organize Imports in Eclipse or NetBeans, I'd get a nice dialog asking me which classes of each of those types I want to import.

In IntelliJ I don't get a dialog at all and I have to F2 to each individual class and Alt+Enter, Enter, Enter to import them manually. And if that worked consistently then I could live with that, but there are often other errors in the way that have nothing to do with imports, and often some of these errors melt away after importing missing classes!

What I need is a way to automatically find the missing imports of ambiguous types, and disambiguate them. Where is this essential feature?