# MVC test with Spring Boot 1.4 imports for get(), status() and content()

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot

[This](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) blog describes some of the test improvements in Spring Boot 1.4. Unfortunately it seems that some important informations are missing. What static import is required to use the methods `get()`, `status()` and `content()` from the following example?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserVehicleController.class)
public class UserVehicleControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserVehicleService userVehicleService;

    @Test
    public void getVehicleShouldReturnMakeAndModel() {
        given(this.userVehicleService.getVehicleDetails("sboot"))
            .willReturn(new VehicleDetails("Honda", "Civic"));

        this.mvc.perform(get("/sboot/vehicle")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you using *Organize imports* feature, every IDE has it. For example in IntelliJ is Ctrl + Alt + O.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8609200/2757140

Comment: I'm searching also for `given` import.

Comment: OK, got it, it's part of `BDDMockito` class. 2h to find it.

Comment: 6.5 years later and SpringBoot folks still leaving off import statements in their documentation. I'm still having terrible time finding imports for these commands.

Answer (score 10):

I already found out:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following guide to use auto import eclipse feature for static import.

[Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports)

The Exact answer to your question is following.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
```