# Optimize invalid imports IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an issue in *Intellij IDEA*. Let's assume that after pretty heavy refactor we have changed one of the package's name. 
As you can see in the example below, package name changed from `kmi` to something different.

[image]

In terms of optimizing imports, `ctrl` + `alt` +  `o` doesn't handle this case

Is there a shorthand that is working on IntelliJ? Definition of shorthand - It is NOT deleting invalid imports and importing them back again. I wonder if IntelliJ can handle it by one shortcut possibly

To be precise - this is NOT duplicate of [IntelliJ Organize Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608710/intellij-organize-imports)
because this shortcut doesn't handle my case

Comment: I think you should change the package's name through "refactor - rename" actions and let IntelliJ handle this kind of issues.

Comment: but we are talking about the case when something went bad, and how to solve this particular issue, not how to avoid it ;)

Comment: Then maybe you can use simple "Search and Replace in Project scope" for package names (previous and new). I know it is not the best answer, but it is something you can use to overcome inconsistencies more easily.

Comment: How did you perform a refactoring that made your code invalid? Refactorings in IntelliJ IDEA would update the imports automatically.

Comment: it is possible to perform refactor without checking for usage. I am just curious if in case of something like above is a way to fix it like in eclipse. Apparently not.