# how to stop intellij from deleting imports like "import javax.servlet.http.*;"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I don't know what i did, but intellij is literally deleting the imports whenever i use "import lib.*".

I'm just trying to write a simple servlet class, but I import everything then later optimize the imports.

How do i disable this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3348855/44522 if it helps.