# How do I stop wildcard Java package imports in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, ide

On IntelliJ Java IDE when I import a class using the keyboard shortcut or take the suggested import, IntelliJ imports the whole package, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  List list = new LinkedList();

}
```

would result in this import line

```
java.util.*;
```

I prefer the IDE to not do a package level import and import explicit classes. 
I want to set this at the global level, so I don't have to deal with this at each project. 
Is there any way to do this?

I am on IntelliJ 13.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Open up preferences and search for "import". This will narrow down the list you need to look through. The screen shot shows the options for when to use single imports vs * (you can see I don't like star imports).

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, this worked, in the past I tried this but the settings didn't stick when I created a new project. I will create a few new projects and see how the setting stays across projects.

Comment: NOTE: Also make sure to set "Class count to use import with *" to a high number as shown in the screenshot by Tracy Snell. Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348816/intellij-never-use-wildcard-imports/25916603#25916603

Comment: Is there really no way to tell Intellij 15 never to use starred imports? I mean without specifying a class count??!

Answer (score 28):

under `File` menu

select `Settings` (ctrl+alt+s)

select `Code Style`

select `Java`

select `Imports` tab

under `General` the check box `Use single class import` will determine whether packages or classes will be imported.

the `Use fully qualified class names` check box  will not use imports rather it will insert full class names directly into the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very detailed and steps clearly listed.

Comment: Useful to know, but not actually what was asked.  The OP wants to keep import statements, just none with `*`s.

Answer (score 13):

IntelliJ version 2020.2.3 (October built)

Preferences > Editor > CodeStyle > Java
in the "General" tab
check "Use Single Class import"
check "Use fully qualified class names"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see all the specific imports without using fully qualified class names, you can do this:

go to Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Set "class count to use import with '*': " to 100 (or any big number)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have autoimport
cancel autoimport
auto-import settings under "Settings → Editor → Auto Import

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. But the following process fixed my problem.

Press key combination `ctrl+alt+O`, then only the needed packages will be added.

Comment: Rao, won't key combination ctrl+alt+o fix remove unnecessary packages?