# Disable wild cart import in intellij Android Studio in kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to turn off wild cart import in java class import.

For example if I am importing **java.util** package's any class then it will import whole java package like **java.util.***. So how can I stop in android studio 3.1.1.

Here is screenshot from my problem.

[image]

I just used only two classes form this package named **Locale** and **Calendar**. But still I have to import whole package so want to stop importing whole package and just import on this two class default.

Also tried this reference link but not working for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348855/5697244

**Note**: I am using kotlin language as development.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Finally got answer by re-search:

Simple steps to disable wildcart import in in **Android Studio** with **Kotlin**. Steps as listed below.

1. In settings>code style>java as mentioned in below screen.

[image]

2. In java import tab apply changes as given in below screen

[image]

3. Also in kotlin tab apply changes as given in below changes

[image]

**Note** : Don't forgot to remove all packages form "packages to use import with *" section in kotlin tab.

Comment: Thanks for referencing Kotlin, I was pulling my hair apart as I made the changes only to the Java Coding Style imports.

Answer (score 3):

Look under `Settings -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Packages to Use Import with '*'` (note, Kotlin, not Java as in the linked question). I've just checked and it does include `java.util.*` at my machine and I didn't edit it before.

Comment: Checking now. Let me check